# Show array in PHP html without repeating rows

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, phpmyadmin

I have the following problem, it turns out that I have the following arrangement:

```
$array85 = array(
            0=> array(
                     "id"=> "15",
                     "estilo"=> "0053",
                     "codigo"=>  "4444444.23",
                     "color"=> "verde",
                     "punto"=>  "23" ,
                     "material"=>  "vacuno" ,
                     "precio"=>  "130" ,
                     "stock_vendido"=> (2),
                     "total"=> "260" ,
                ),
            1=> array(
                     "id"=> "16" ,
                     "estilo"=> "0053" ,
                     "codigo"=> "4444444.25" ,
                     "color"=>  "verde" ,
                     "punto"=> "25" ,
                     "material"=> "vacuno" ,
                     "precio"=> "130" ,
                    "stock_vendido"=> (1) ,
                     "total"=>  "130" ,
                ),
            2=> array(
                     "id"=> "10" ,
                    "estilo"=>  "0058" ,
                     "codigo"=>"1232323.23" ,
                     "color"=> "rojo" ,
                     "punto"=>"23" ,
                     "material"=> "sintetico" ,
                     "precio"=>  "2.8" ,
                     "stock_vendido"=> (3) ,
                     "total"=>  "8.4" 
                 )
        );
```

at the moment of showing this arrangement in an HTML table with the help of a foreach it generates the table but it shows me 3 rows. Here the detail is that I only have to show 2 rows, since a style is repeated, however I must show those two rows but when the style is the same I must also show the shoe point I buy. Something similar to this, I did it in excel the way the table should look like in html:

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ1zA.png)

where description is only the style, and if there is more than one point of a style as it is added in its respective cell point of the shoe.

I hope you can help me friends, I would appreciate it a lot of friends.

So far I show the information of that arrangement, but as I mention it shows me 3 rows.

```
echo '<table style="font-size:8px; padding:5px 10px;">

    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:8px; width:78.14px; text-align:justify">Descripción</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">22</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">22.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">23</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">23.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">24</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">24.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">25</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">25.5</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">26</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">26.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">27</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">27.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">28</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">28.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">29</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">29.5</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">30</td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">30.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">31</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">31.5</td>
            <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">32</td>

            ';
        foreach ($array85 as $val){
                $name = $val["estilo"] . '-' . $val["material"] . '-' . $val["color"];
                $punto = $val["punto"];

                if ($punto == "22") {
                    $stock22 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "22.5") {
                    $stock225 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "23") {
                    $stock23 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "23.5") {
                    $stock235 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "24") {
                    $stock24 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "24.5") {
                    $stock245 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "25") {
                    $stock25 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "25.5") {
                    $stock255 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "26") {
                    $stock26 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "26.5") {
                    $stock265 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "27") {
                    $stock27 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "27.5") {
                    $stock275 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "28") {
                    $stock28 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "28.5") {
                    $stock285 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "29") {
                    $stock29 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "29.5") {
                    $stock295 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "30") {
                    $stock30 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "30.5") {
                    $stock305 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "31") {
                    $stock31 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "31.5") {
                    $stock315 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                } else if ($punto == "32") {
                    $stock32 = $val["stock_vendido"];

                }
                echo '<tr>



                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:8px; width:78.14px; text-align:justify">'.$name.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock22.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock225.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock23.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock235.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock24.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock245.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock25.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock255.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock26.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock265.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock27.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock275.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock28.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock285.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock29.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock295.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock30.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock305.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock31.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:34.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock315.'</td>
                    <td style="border: 0.1px solid #666; background-color:white; font-size:6px; width:30.14px; text-align:center">'.$stock32.'</td>



    </tr>
   ';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

This is my attempt at solution but here I only count how many times the style is repeated, and I can not show the acquired units of each shoe size...

```
$datos = $array85;
        $array_tallajes = array();
        foreach ($datos as $item) {
            $value = $item["estilo"] . "-" . $item["material"] . "-" . $item["color"];
            $punto = $item["punto"];
            if (array_key_exists($value, $array_tallajes)) {
                if (array_key_exists($punto, $array_tallajes[$value])) {
                    $array_tallajes[$value][$punto] += 1;
                } else {
                    $array_tallajes[$value][$punto] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $array_tallajes[$value] = [$punto => 1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `I only have to show 2 rows, since a style is repeated` - how is this, I see no style field and each has a different ID.  How do you decide it's a duplicate.  The problem here is that your database is allowing you to enter data that you call a duplicate.  If you have no use for that row, then fix the process that allows it to happen and don't bandaid the end result by removing it (if possible)...

Comment: Is it id 15 & 16 that is duplicated? If yes, what makes them duplicate?

Comment: This whole if mess you got, with these numbers `$stock225` etc can be done with one or 2 lines of code `$k = str_replace(".", "", $val["stock_vendido"]);` then `${"stock$k}" = $val["stock_vendido"];`  (Sandbox Example)[http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b431767dae178ca075e687ee09dc1fc0ef10e6f3] - then you can remove all those if conditions.  You must also output the HTML after the loop, once all those dynamic variables are set, not within the loop.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `"estilo" => "0053"`. This looks like a sales report, or stock tracking, aggregating different sizes and units sold.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix its correct,

Comment: the array is a sale that is made in a POS system, what happens is that there are equal styles although these have different ID, this happens because each style is a shoe that has its due measure. I was showing the sales note of how the array comes, and it shows, but what happens if there are more items, the sheet would go down, so it is necessary to accommodate the sale horizontally, in case the client carries similar styles, only one row will be shown and in that row the units purchased will be accommodated as it appears in the image.

Comment: Why don't you use something like array_filter on the array prior to running it through the foreach. That said, if this behaviour isn't expected 'patching it up' rather than fixing it will cause more pain later down the line. It would be worth noting that the if statements make things a little messy, I'd also question comparing the value with a string as the output is an integer

Comment: @LiamSorsby Hi I tried to filter the results with the php array_key_exists function, but it did not work

Comment: @JoseRangel Can you update your question with your attempt please?

Comment: @LiamSorsby ready  my friend

Comment: @JoseRangel I meant the native function to filter the array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I still do not try that function, allow me a moment to do tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is already aggregated and can't be any repeated combinations of 'estilo' and 'punto', a simple reindex of your array will do:

```
foreach($array85 as $el){
    $keys = ['stock_vendido', 'punto'];
    $size = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

   if (!isset($report[$el['estilo']])) {
      $shoe = array_filter($el, function($v, $k) use ($keys) { return !in_array($k, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
      unset($shoe['total']);
      $report[$el['estilo']] = $shoe;
      $report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'] = [];
    } 
    $report[$el['estilo']]['tallajes'][$size['punto']] = $size['stock_vendido'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/A5tQv) with HTML output and calculations.